# Render/display Panel's page outside 'content'

Tags: panels

I'm fairly new with Panels. By default Panels content will be displayed inside

```
 <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

Is it possible to display it outside the content? 
For example if I made another placeholder and display inside it?

```
 <?php print render($page['content_panel']); ?>
```

**NOTE:** I'm using Drupal 7.

The reason I want to do this because the
 `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>`
is sitting inside

```
<div class="container content-main">
  <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
</div>
```

All `contents/pages` will be displayed inside `content-main` except 1 page which I don't want it to be inside the `content-main` div.

The `content-main` class have `css` which I don't need it in the panel.

The 1 page I want it to have its own `<?php print render($page['content_panel']); ?>` so that I can assign the panel to it and located outside the `content-main` div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use mini panels, mini panels shiped with panel module and you can use it as block, any mini panels you create will be listed under blocks, just assign it to the region you want

Comment: hai. yeah. i can achieved what i want with your suggestion. just wondering if it can be done using <?php print render($page['content_panel']); ?>

Comment: I think i did it ones i the way you describe,  try to google embedded panel in tpl file